# How to pass the Arn of a Step function to another function in a CloudFormation stack?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions

I created a step function in a CloudFormation stack, and I need to call that function from another function in the stack once it's deployed. I have no idea how to do that, and I'm getting circular dependencies.

Basically I'm trying to pass an environment variable to the function that's the ARN of the step function.

Here's the CloudFormation code :

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
    reports stack

Globals:
    Function:
        Timeout: 120
        MemorySize: 2048
        Runtime: python3.9
        Environment:
            Variables:
                STEP_FUNCTION:  !GetAtt Research.Arn   ### =====> how do i do that ?

Parameters:

    ProjectName:
        Description: Name of the Project
        Type: String
        Default: Project

Resources:

    MyApi:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
      Properties:
        StageName: Prod
        TracingEnabled: true
        Cors: 
          AllowMethods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT'"
          AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
          AllowOrigin: "'*'"
        

    List:
        DependsOn: VideoResearch
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
        Properties:
            CodeUri: functions/
            Handler: get.get         
            Events:
                List:
                    Type: Api 
                    Properties:
                        RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
                        Path: /reports
                        Method: GET
            Policies:
            (...)


    ################ STEP FUNCTION ################

    Research:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
      Properties:
        CodeUri: functions/
        Handler: runResearch.research
        Policies:
            (...)

  
    StepFunctionToHandleResearchRole:
      Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - !Sub states.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com
              Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
        Path: "/"
        Policies:
          (...)


    # 
    StepFunctionToHandleVideosResearch:
      Type: "AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine"
      Properties:
        DefinitionString: !Sub |
              {
                "StartAt": "Research",
                "States": {
                  "Research": {
                    "Type": "Task",
                    "Resource": "${VideoResearch.Arn}", 
                    "End": true
                  }
                }
              }
        RoleArn: !GetAtt [ StepFunctionToHandleResearchRole, Arn ]


Outputs:

  (...)

  # I also tried to export the arn of the function
```

In my function's code I have :

`stepFunctionARN = os.environ['STEP_FUNCTION']`

Comment: By using globals, all the parameters will be applied to all functions, even Research. You need to remove the env variables from globals and just put it inside the function that will trigger the research function

Comment: The fact it's added to all functions is not a problem, the problem I have is how to get the step function ARN sent to the function without a circular dependency. Any idea how ?

Comment: @AnthonyB. Your solution actually worked. I tried it and removed the global variable and replaced it by a local variable with a DependsOn dependency worked like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

@Anthony B. posted the answer in the comments : the problem was related to the fact I added the dependency as global variables, it created a circular dependency (API=> local function <= API looking for function's ARN => doesn't work).

If you remove the global variable and add a local variable, with a "DependsOn: Research" than everything works.

API=>created => creates first function, get Arn => than creates other functions and provide ARN